# Azure Point-To-Site connectivity on exiting virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I was using Azure Connect, but found that the new Point-to-Site VPN is replacing Azure Connect.  So I have an existing network set up that I want to configure.

However, when I click on the "Configure Point-To-Site connectivity" checkbox, nothing happens.

At the top of the page, it says "The virtual network is in use. Configuration changes are limited to adding new subnets."  However, this can't mean that I can't configure the Point-to-Site VPN, since it's supposed to be a replacement for Azure Connect, and Azure Connect let me add computers to this network.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that this is no longer the case. I've just successfully created a new Point-to-Site VPN connection on a virtual network that had existing VMs on it (as well as other external load-balanced endpoints)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Point-to-Site VPN has to be configured before you deploy any VMs to the virtual network. This also applies to Site-To-Site VPN.

Comment: Do you know if this is just a temporary limitation, or a long-term thing?  It sure does sound like a huge flaw.  You couldn't possibly know all of the developers who will eventually need access to your network at the time you set it up.